# Android Billing v3 - Subscription - Product Not Found

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I am trying to implement Subscriptions for the first time. I am using BillingClient v3.0.1. It is contract so I am not the owner of the Google Play account. The account owner has set up financials for the account and has configured the API. I have created the subscription products in the Google Play console, added the billing library through Gradle and `com.android.vending.BILLING` in the manifest, and published a build on the Closed Alpha track for internal testing.

I initialize the billing client successfully

```
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mContext)
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .setListener(this)
                .build();

        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult) {
                ...
            }

            @Override public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                ...
            }
        });
```

and everything works, I retrieve the list of products

```
            SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSkusList(skuList)
                    .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
                    .build();
            billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                @Override public void onSkuDetailsResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<SkuDetails> list) {
                    ...
            });
```

and that too is successful, but when I try to purchase the product on a real device with a build running the same version code as the Alpha testing track version using:

```
        BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSkuDetails(product)
                .build();
        BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(mContext, billingFlowParams);
```

The pop-up shows an Error in the pop-up "The item you were attempting to purchase could not be found".

I have been going through everything I can find (short of receipt validation, which will be next up after I can actually complete a purchase), but am stuck.

Any advice / thoughts?

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

In 'desperation' -> Well actually because I had nothing better to try, I updated the build on GooglePlay alpha test track and ran the exact same build on my test device and now it is working, no other changes, but progress.